# Game of Life program in Java

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I've been trying to make a Game of Life program in a fairly simple (yet maybe wrong) way. Technically it seems to work but when I tried to run some test-cases the results did not fit the examples online.

Here's the main class:

```
  package gameOfLife;import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import gameOfLife.Cell.State;

public class CreateGame extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener, KeyListener {


private enum GameState {
    SETTING, START
}

private GameState state = GameState.SETTING;
private Image image;
private Graphics second;
private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[200][120];
private int indexI = 1;
private int indexJ = 1;

@Override
public void init() {
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setFocusable(true);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Game of Life - Settings");

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(i * 5, j * 5);
        }
    }
    addMouseListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    super.init();
}

@Override
public void start() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    super.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (state == GameState.START) {
            for(int i=1; i<cells.length-1; i++){
                for(int j=1; j<cells[0].length-1; j++){
                    update(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(125);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void update(int i, int j) { //updating the cells into ALIVE/DEAD state
    int[] neighbors = new int[8];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
        neighbors[index] = 0;
    if (cells[i - 1][j - 1].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[0] = 1;
    if (cells[i][j - 1].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[1] = 1;
    if (cells[i + 1][j - 1].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[2] = 1;
    if (cells[i - 1][j].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[3] = 1;
    if (cells[i + 1][j].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[4] = 1;
    if (cells[i - 1][j + 1].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[5] = 1;
    if (cells[i][j + 1].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[6] = 1;
    if (cells[i + 1][j + 1].state == State.ALIVE)
        neighbors[7] = 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
        sum += neighbors[index];
    if ((sum < 2 || sum > 3) && cells[i][j].state == State.ALIVE)
        cells[i][j].state = State.DEAD;
    else {
        if (sum == 3 && cells[i][j].state == State.DEAD)
            cells[i][j].state = State.ALIVE;
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle r;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++) {
            if (cells[i][j].state == State.ALIVE) {
                r = cells[i][j].getCell();
                g.fillRect((int) r.getX(), (int) r.getY(), (int) r.getWidth(), (int) r.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }
    super.paint(g);
}

@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (state == GameState.SETTING) {
        int x = e.getX() - e.getX() % 5;
        int y = e.getY() - e.getY() % 5;

        cells[x / 5][y / 5].born();
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        if(state == GameState.START)
            state = GameState.SETTING;
        else 
            state = GameState.START;
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I made the program in a way that by pressing the Space key you change the game state from SETTING (clicking on the screen to create cells which pauses the game) and START which makes the game run on its own.
Cell is a class I created which contains the Rectangle and state:

```
package gameOfLife;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Cell {

final int Measure = 5;
public static enum State{
    DEAD, ALIVE
}

private Rectangle cell;
private int x, y;

public State state;

public void born(){
    state = State.ALIVE;
}

public Cell(int x, int y){
    state = State.DEAD;
    cell = new Rectangle(x, y, Measure, Measure);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Rectangle getCell(){
    return this.cell;
}
```

}

If anyone can test it and tell me what's wrong with the program logic it will be great, because overall its working, but there's probably some minor issue I can't put my finger on which screws it up.

Comment: This may be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This may be appropriate here if you make a reproducible example, with sample input, a description of the expected output, and possibly a sample of the wrong output. "Here is code, find the error" is not what people usually respond to here.

Comment: Well I'm sorry, I don't really know how this place works. I thought I could post it as I did and if there're any clarifications or examples of output needed I'll post it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the error - you were refreshing the state of each cell as you iterated through the grid, but the correct way is to create a grid of new cell states during the iteration, then set the existing cell states to the new cell states in one go, if that makes sense.

Amended code which seems to work:

```
public class CreateGame
    extends Applet
    implements Runnable, MouseListener, KeyListener
{

  private enum GameState
  {
    SETTING, START
  }

  private GameState state = GameState.SETTING;

  private Image image;

  private Graphics second;

  private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[200][120];

  private int indexI = 1;

  private int indexJ = 1;

  @Override
  public void init()
  {
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setFocusable(true);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Game of Life - Settings");

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++)
      {
        cells[i][j] = new Cell(i * 5, j * 5);
      }
    }
    addMouseListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    super.init();
  }

  @Override
  public void start()
  {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    super.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      if (state == GameState.START)
      {
        Cell[][] newCells = new Cell[200][120];

        for (int i = 0; i < newCells.length; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < newCells[0].length; j++)
          {
            newCells[i][j] = new Cell(i * 5, j * 5);
          }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < cells.length - 1; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 1; j < cells[0].length - 1; j++)
          {
            update(newCells, i, j);
          }
        }

        cells = newCells; // update all cell states in one go
      }
      repaint();
      try
      {
        Thread.sleep(125);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public void update(Cell[][] newCells, int i, int j)
  { // updating the cells into ALIVE/DEAD state

    int[] neighbors = new int[8];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
      neighbors[index] = 0;
    if (cells[i - 1][j - 1].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[0] = 1;
    if (cells[i][j - 1].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[1] = 1;
    if (cells[i + 1][j - 1].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[2] = 1;
    if (cells[i - 1][j].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[3] = 1;
    if (cells[i + 1][j].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[4] = 1;
    if (cells[i - 1][j + 1].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[5] = 1;
    if (cells[i][j + 1].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[6] = 1;
    if (cells[i + 1][j + 1].state == State.ALIVE)
      neighbors[7] = 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
      sum += neighbors[index];

    if (cells[i][j].state == State.ALIVE)
    {
      if ((sum < 2 || sum > 3))
      {
        newCells[i][j].state = State.DEAD;
      }
      else // sum == 2 or 3
      {
        newCells[i][j].state = State.ALIVE;
      }
    }
    else if (cells[i][j].state == State.DEAD)
    {
      if (sum == 3)
      {
        newCells[i][j].state = State.ALIVE;
      }
    }  
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle r;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++)
      {
        if (cells[i][j].state == State.ALIVE)
        {
          r = cells[i][j].getCell();
          g.fillRect((int) r.getX(), (int) r.getY(), (int) r.getWidth(), (int) r.getHeight());
        }
      }
    }
    super.paint(g);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(Graphics g)
  {
    if (image == null)
    {
      image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
      second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
  {
    if (state == GameState.SETTING)
    {
      int x = e.getX() - e.getX() % 5;
      int y = e.getY() - e.getY() % 5;

      cells[x / 5][y / 5].born();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
      if (state == GameState.START)
        state = GameState.SETTING;
      else
        state = GameState.START;
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Tried to upvote your comment but appearntly I need more reputation for that. Just one more thing, the program appears to work fine now, but I tried to run this test case (which is supposed to run on an infinite loop): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_(cellular_automaton)#/media/File:Game_of_life_glider_gun.svg and it didn't work, is something wrong with the code logic?

Comment: No problem, pleased I could help. It's possible there's still a logic error, I've not checked the rest of the code. How are you setting up the test pattern that's not working, are you creating the pattern in code or by hand? Asking because a single different cell in the initial configuration will result in very different behaviour. Also how is it failing?

Comment: I set the pattern by han, just now working on code setting. I set it accurately though (did it several times and checked more than once). The pattern falls apart after shooting to "spaceships". Here's an image of how it looks like at the end: http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=nd5jq5jzmktu.png

Comment: Hmm, I'd definitely try to rule out possible error in the initial pattern config, by writing some code to pre-populate the grid. Maybe create a function that accepts a 2D int array of x, y coordinates to set to initially alive?

Comment: That's sort of what I've already started working on already, only instead of an Array of coordinates the function will take an array of 0's and 1's for living and dead cells. Anyway thanks for you help, I think I'll try to manage it on my own from now :)